# select and modify specific item of the same class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to hover over and change a specific item in the list of items without all of them items being changed when I hover over one. I have some divs with the class 'item'.

```
function itemHover(){

    $(".item").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();
        $(".item-button").css("opacity","1");
        $(".description").css("visibility","visible");
        $(".description").css("opacity","1");
        $(".image-container").css("opacity","0.1")
    })

    $(".item").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".item-button").css("opacity","0");
        $(".description").css("visibility","hidden");
        $(".description").css("opacity","0");
        $(".image-container").css("opacity","1")
    })

}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="item">               

    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <div class="image-container"></div>
        <div class="title">
            Macbook Pro 15" retina with case and cover
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            £99999999999999
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>MacBook Pro witht.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-button">
           Buy this
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

What Jquery will only select that specific item i am hovering over and change elements css of that SPECIFIC item and only that.

Comment: use a context based search like `$(this).find(".item-button").css()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LfsMG/1/

Comment: Can't you do this entirely in CSS, without using Javascript? With CSS selectors like `.item:hover .item-button`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
$(itemHover);

function itemHover(){

    $(".item").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn()
        .find(".item-button").css("opacity","1").end()
        .find(".description").css("visibility","visible")
        .(".description").css("opacity","1").end()
        .find(".image-container").css("opacity","0.1");
    });

    $(".item").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this)
        .find(".item-button").css("opacity","0").end()
        .find(".description").css("visibility","hidden")
        .(".description").css("opacity","0").end()
        .find(".image-container").css("opacity","1");
    });

}
```